# If you declare war on the same civ twice, do you get the "You declared war on our friend" penalty twice?

Tags: civilization-4, civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

If you declare war on the same civ twice in Civ 4, do you get the "You declared war on our friend" penalty twice (i.e. for a total of -2 favourability rather than -1)?

Comment: **yes**, you do.

Comment: I would think that you wouldn't have the option of declaring war on the same faction twice -- that option should be unavailable if you're already at war. I hardly played Civ 4 in favor of 5 (and now 6) though...